# REGEX to find .exe extension in a particular string.?

Tags: java, regex, jsp

I am trying to setup a REGEX in my java code where any given string ending with a particular expression like .exe should give a boolean true value else if should return false value. What should be the regex expression.?

Comment: Seriously?   You should just read the javadocs for `Pattern`.  This task is a no-brainer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need regex for this, just use `String#endsWith`:

```
String file = "some_file.exe";
if (file.endsWith(".exe")) {
    System.out.println("MATCH");
}
```

If you wanted to use regex, you could use `String#matches` here:

```
String file = "some_file.exe";
if (file.matches(".*\\.exe")) {
    System.out.println("MATCH");
}
```

Comment: The above given solutions are returning MATCH if i am giving some_file.exe.exe ., I don't want that,, i want it should return false for .exe , abc.exe.exe and true for azbc.exe.

Comment: I don't understand your logic.  Can you explain it better, _in your original question_, and _not_ here as comment?

Answer (score 1):

Here, we might want to create a capturing group on the right and add any extensions that we like in it using logical ORs, then swipe to left and collect the filenames, maybe similar to:

```
^(.*\.)(exe|mp3|mp4)$
```

which in this case would be just:

```
^(.*\.)(exe)$
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vQEuvT/1/)

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "^(.*\\.)(exe|mp3|mp4)$";
final String string = "anything_you_wish_here.exe\n"
     + "anything_you_wish_here.mp4\n"
     + "anything_you_wish_here.mp3\n"
     + "anything_you_wish_here.jpg\n"
     + "anything_you_wish_here.png";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

#### Demo

This snippet just shows that how the capturing groups work:

```js
const regex = /^(.*\.)(exe|mp3|mp4)$/gm;
const str = `anything_you_wish_here.exe
anything_you_wish_here.mp4
anything_you_wish_here.mp3
anything_you_wish_here.jpg
anything_you_wish_here.png`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified or changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/vQEuvT/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]